# FileUpload Control

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I include 6 fileupload control,

Now, I just select one file  and I click my save button, its saved succesfuly bitmap.

But, I select 6 files and I click save button, IE or Firefox says that, PAGE CAN NOT SHOW.
Why is say PAGE CAN NOT SHOW message?
Please help!

The Button1 Click Code is; its save 6 fileupload control's files.

```
    if(FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        String _dosya = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmmssfff");
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("")+"/temp/"+_dosya+".jpg");
        System.Drawing.Image _resim = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("") + "/temp/" + _dosya + ".jpg");
        HelperClass _class = new HelperClass();
        _resim = _class.FixedSize(_resim, 150, 150);
        _resim.Save(Server.MapPath("") + "/resimler/" + _dosya + ".jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        _imgAnaResim ="resimler/"+ _dosya+".jpg";

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
    if(FileUpload2.HasFile)
    {
        String _dosya = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmmssfff");
        FileUpload2.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("")+"/temp/" + _dosya + ".jpg");
        System.Drawing.Image _resim = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("")+"/temp/" + _dosya + ".jpg");
        HelperClass _class = new HelperClass();
        _resim = _class.FixedSize(_resim, 150, 150);
        _resim.Save(Server.MapPath("")+"/resimler/" + _dosya + ".jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        _imgResim1 = "resimler/" + _dosya + ".jpg";

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
    if (FileUpload3.HasFile)
    {
        String _dosya = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmmssfff");
        FileUpload3.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("") + "/temp/" + _dosya + ".jpg");
        System.Drawing.Image _resim = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("") + "/temp/" + _dosya + ".jpg");
        HelperClass _class = new HelperClass();
        _resim = _class.FixedSize(_resim, 150, 150);
        _resim.Save(Server.MapPath("") + "/resimler/" + _dosya + ".jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        _imgResim2 = "resimler/" + _dosya + ".jpg";

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
    if (FileUpload4.HasFile)
    {
        String _dosya = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmmssfff");
        FileUpload4.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("") + "/temp/" + _dosya + ".jpg");
        System.Drawing.Image _resim = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("") + "/temp/" + _dosya + ".jpg");
        HelperClass _class = new HelperClass();
        _resim = _class.FixedSize(_resim, 150, 150);
        _resim.Save(Server.MapPath("") + "/resimler/" + _dosya + ".jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        _imgResim3 = "resimler/" + _dosya + ".jpg";

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
    if (FileUpload5.HasFile)
    {
        String _dosya = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmmssfff");
        FileUpload5.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("") + "/temp/" + _dosya + ".jpg");
        System.Drawing.Image _resim = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("") + "/temp/" + _dosya + ".jpg");
        HelperClass _class = new HelperClass();
        _resim = _class.FixedSize(_resim, 150, 150);
        _resim.Save(Server.MapPath("") + "/resimler/" + _dosya + ".jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        _imgResim4 = "resimler/" + _dosya + ".jpg";

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
    if (FileUpload6.HasFile)
    {
        String _dosya = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmmssfff");
        FileUpload6.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("") + "/temp/" + _dosya + ".jpg");
        System.Drawing.Image _resim = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("") + "/temp/" + _dosya + ".jpg");
        HelperClass _class = new HelperClass();
        _resim = _class.FixedSize(_resim, 150, 150);
        _resim.Save(Server.MapPath("") + "/resimler/" + _dosya + ".jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        _imgResim5 = "resimler/" + _dosya + ".jpg";

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
```

Comment: Did you try debugging your code instead of asking others to do this for you?

Comment: Yes,it very interesing, FileUploa1 , FileUpload2 ,FileUpload3,FileUpload4,FileUpload5 are have files And I click Save Button its OK, SAVED all pictuer. BUT when I add FileUpload6 has file ( all of them have files ) IE says Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage. This error I see when I add six files selected.

Comment: SOLVED, I FIX like this; in web.config file add this code   <httpRuntime 
    maxRequestLength="1048576"
    executionTimeout="3600"
  />
 inside system.web tag :)

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED,

add this code in web.config file inside system.web tag

< httpRuntime 
    maxRequestLength="1048576"
    executionTimeout="3600"
/>